# Quarkus / hibernate-orm caching of collections (@OneToMany)

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, quarkus, second-level-cache

I have to objects (Garage,Car) as it's described bellow .
My questions is why when I try to access something like Garage.cars on my endpoints logic , the field "cars" from Garage is queried from database (insead of the cache) , even if in configuration file I set up the property quarkus.hibernate-orm.cache."org.acme.Garage#cars".expiration.max-idle = 86400 (Garage.cars) cache expires after 100 seconds (what I want is to set this to 86400)
I just want to ask if it is a normal flow or maybe anyone has been struggling with the same problem .

My entities looks like this :

```
@Entity @Table(name="GarageTable") @Cacheable @ApplicationScoped
```

public class Garage extends PanacheEntityBase {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "GarId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long garageId;

@ManyToMany()
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@JoinTable(name="garage_cars" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "garage_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
public Set<Car> cars;

@Column(name="GarageDimension" , length = 10)
public Long dimension;

public static Garage findGarageById(Long id) {
    return findById(id);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Garage [garageId=" + garageId + ", cars=" + cars + ", dimension=" + dimension + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: have two objects * (instead of have to objects , sorry )

Comment: The best would be to enable TRACE logging of `org.hibernate` package and see what cache related messages appear when accesing `.cars`. One reason for the DB to be queried could be that the there's been a `Car` instance has been updated. That would trigger a re-query.

Comment: The fact is that no instance of Car object is modified . When something is changed the fact that the query is triggered is logic , but no when nothing is happened .

Comment: When I try to get Garage object ( for example : Garage.getById() ) even if the garage contains cars , cars getting query is not triggered , only when I refer to field Garage.cars it is triggered .

Comment: It's a while since I've explored this in detail (hence my suggestion, once again, for you to check the `TRACE` logging, which you can combine with looking at the source code), but IIRC collections are loaded lazily. So, it would make sense that the query is only triggered when the `cars` collection is accessed.

Comment: But, I don't know why the query would keep repeating in the absence of modifications. Maybe some expiration kicking in? Logging and source code are your friends :)